# SQLAlchemy / PostgreSQL not creating column with the correct timestamp format

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy, timezone

I have the following table I'm creating.  After running this in a script to populate a database, the `created_at` columns come back with a value of "2018-10-24 19:47:22.60331".

I'm not getting the time zone offset even though https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT shows that function as adding the time zone offset.

```
def simulation_version_metadata(metadata):
    simulation_version = Table('simulation_version', metadata,
                               Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                               Column('simulation_id', None,
                                      ForeignKey('simulation.id')),
                               Column('created_at', DateTime,
                                      server_default=func.current_timestamp()),
                               Column('updated_at', DateTime,
                                      server_default=func.current_timestamp()),
                               )
    return simulation_version
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DateTime`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime) columns in SQLAlchemy default to `timezone=False`. Set `timezone=True` like:

```
Column('created_at', DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.current_timestamp())
```